# Best way to encrypt FILESTREAM data?

Tags: encryption, filestream

I was wondering what is the way for the FILESTREAM data encryption (for example `.docx` files) in SQL Server? Is it Microsoft EFS or there is another solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This site is not for `best way` questions.

Comment: This was a very useful question. The (perhaps implied) ask is "how can FILESTREAM data be encrypted". This is important because the at-rest encryption supplied by the MS SQL product explicitly does not include the FILESTREAM data.

Comment: You mention EFS, but there is also BitLocker which can be used to transparently encrypt the FILESTREAM data and can employ 256-bit AES.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, there's no encryption built into the FILESTREAM feature.  I would generally expect the application fronting the database to handle any encryption of the data before sending it to the database and decrypting after retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

> "Is it Microsoft EFS or there is another solution?"

Since you asked about other solutions as well, there are two third party products that offer alternatives to TDE including FileStream encryption. They both work with all versions and editions of SQL Server. One is NetLib Encryptionizer for SQL Server and the other is DBDefence. Although they both work differently. Encryptionizer sits between SQL Server and the OS, while DBDefence injects code into the running SQL process using the (now defunct) Detours SDK.  (Disclaimer: I am with [NetLib Security](https://netlibsecurity.com)).